# Prevent Depth First Search Algorithm from getting stuck in an infinite loop ,8 Puzzle

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

So my code works for basic 8 Puzzle problems, but when I test it with harder puzzle configurations it runs into an infinite loop. Can someone please edit my code to prevent this from happening. Note that I have included code that prevents the loops or cycles. I tried including the the iterative depth first search technique, but that too did not work. Can someone please review my code.

```
    /** Implementation for the Depth first search algorithm */
static boolean depthFirstSearch(String start, String out ){    

    LinkedList<String> open = new LinkedList<String>();
    open.add(start);

    Set<String> visitedStates = new HashSet<String>();      // to prevent the cyle or loop

    LinkedList<String> closed = new LinkedList<String>();

    boolean isGoalState= false;

    while((!open.isEmpty()) && (isGoalState != true) ){

        String x = open.removeFirst();

        System.out.println(printPuzzle(x)+"\n\n");
        jtr.append(printPuzzle(x) +"\n\n");

        if(x.equals(out)){               // if x is the goal
            isGoalState = true;
            break;
        }
        else{
                                                                // generate children of x 
            LinkedList<String> children = getChildren(x);

            closed.add(x);               // put x on closed
            open.remove(x);             // since x is now in closed, take it out from open

            //eliminate the children of X if its on open or closed ?
            for(int i=0; i< children.size(); i++){
                if(open.contains(children.get(i))){
                    children.remove(children.get(i));
                }
                else if(closed.contains(children.get(i))){
                    children.remove(children.get(i));
                }
            }


            // put remaining children on left end of open   
            for(int i= children.size()-1 ; i>=0 ; i--){
                if ( !visitedStates.contains(children.get(i))) {   // check if state already visited
                       open.addFirst(children.get(i));              // add last child first, and so on 
                       visitedStates.add(children.get(i));
                }
            }

        }
    }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You need to learn how to debug your own code. Start here: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I asked for someone to review the algorithm , not for someone to tell me to debug my own code. You are being faulty.

Comment: You can't always get what you ask for. Even if you do, it won't help you much in the long run. Learning to debug your own code is the one of the most crucial skills you'll need to code effectively.

Comment: As you surely read about depth-first search, you'll also find other search algorithms (A* for example) plus the reasons why depth-first isn't useful for more complex problems. I won't do your job of debugging your code. Maybe even there's nothing wrong with it, and it's just the wrong algorithm for the problem complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the positions that you are considering into a https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html with a priority based on how close they are to being solved.

So what you do is take the closest position off of the queue, and add in all of the one move options from there that haven't yet been processed.  Then repeat.  You'll spent most of your time exploring possibilities that are close to solved instead of just moving randomly forever.

Now your question is "how close are we to solving it".  One approach is to take the sum of all of the taxicab distances between where squares are and where they need to be.  A better heuristic may be to give more weight to getting squares away from the corner in place first.  If you get it right, changing your heuristic should be easy.